# How do I convert a set of latitude/longitude coordinates with timestamps to a GPX tracklog?

Tags: convert, csv, gpx, tracklog

Converting tracks from a GPX track to a CSV table or some other format is relatively easy, but I'm looking to go the other way. I have a table of point locations logged with a handheld GPS, with timestamps. I need to convert them to a GPX file with a tracklog containing those points so they can be used with some other software to geotag some photos. I can convert them to GPX waypoints easily enough using QGIS/GDAL, but not to a GPX tracklog, the timestamps are lost.

Here's the header of my CSV:

```
Lon,Lat,Altitude,NewTrack,TimeStamp,Datum,InternalTime
```

Comment: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input ?

Comment: @Mapperz That worked, thanks. I've used that tool once or twice for other things but it didn't seem like it would account for the timestamps in my table, but it did.

Comment: you can do this with python using this tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPS Visualizer will pass your time stamps to gpx format.

Using the online tools will preserve your timestamp in the .csv file.

> Convert a GPS file to plain text or GPX
>
> This form reads a tracklog or waypoint file (in a recognized format)
>   or plain-text tabular data, and converts it to an easy-to-read
>   tab-delimited or CSV text file, or to a GPX file.

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

Answer (score 2):

The question was asked years ago, so if you are searching for this recently and you are using or willing to use Python >= 3.5, you can use [gpx_converter](https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter).

Install using pip

```
pip install gpx_converter
```

then use it by calling the csv_to_gpx in your case:

```
from gpx_converter import Converter

Converter(input_file='your_input.csv').csv_to_gpx(lats_colname='Lat',
                                                 longs_colname='Lon',
                                                 output_file='your_input.gpx')
```