# Geotagging photos with Point Shape via Time Stamp

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, point

I have waypoints which I marked with a GPS device - unfortunately no track/route. And I have photos which I took at the same day.
Now I want to interpolate the points to line and use this line to geotag my photos.

With QGIS and the plugin "point to path" it's easy to get a line shape. This line shape can be saved as a gpx-track.
With the Freeware "GeoSetter" it's easy to geotag photos with a gpx-track.

But when I try this (Point to Path -> save line shape as gpx -> geotag photos with gpx), GeoSetter complains that the gpx-file doesn't have coordinates with time stamps.

So, how do I get the time stamp of the waypoints into the gpx-track?

Comment: could you maybe share some data to have a look at?

Comment: I had nearly the same question a while back: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94087/how-do-i-convert-a-csv-of-latitude-longitude-coordinates-with-timestamps-to-a-gp , it's not a QGIS solution but it does work. I couldn't figure out another way to convert points to a GPX track while preserving the timestamps in the points.

Comment: What GPS are you using? Some of their utility software has the ability to convert waypoints to a route or track, which could then be saved as a gpx file. There are also some third party tools out there that should be able to do the same. Garmin's MapSource or BaseCamp, and GPS Babel all come to mind. There's some online tools as well like the one suggested at Dan C's linked question.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I used this tool years ago but forgot it completely. I haven't tried it yet but I will and I'm shure that this will work - it's a great tool! ... if not, I can upload some data. Thanks Bernd for this offer.